# jquery find closest given class

Tags: php, jquery

I've created a option list with radio buttons and it looks like this:

```
<div class="option_list" style="width:150px; display:none; margin-top:0px;">
    <form id="formSales">
        <ul>
             <li><input type="radio" value="2012" name="YEAR" /></li>
             <li><input type="radio" value="2011" name="YEAR" /></li>
             <li><input type="radio" value="2010" name="YEAR" /></li>
             <li><input type="radio" value="2009" name="YEAR" /></li>    
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="SALES" />
   </form>
</div>
<div class="table_content_results">
   <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

With jquery I post the form and I want to get that result in the div with the class results
underneath the div with class option_list

```
$(".option_list ul li").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data: $(this).parent('form').serialize(),
        complete: function(data) {

            $(this).siblings('.results').html(data.responseText);
        }
    });
    $(this).parent(".option_list").slideToggle(200);

    var value = $('input[name="YEAR"]:checked').val();
    $("#yearValue").text(value);
});​
```

I use the class in jQuery because i want to duplicate the same option_list for another form on the same page.

The problem is to get the results of data.php in the div with class results.

I hope somebody has an answer for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the `div` with the class `results` already exist ?

Comment: where is results div. i cant see it

Comment: I changed my post, in one way or another the div dissapeared but now it's visible again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$(this).siblings('.results').html(data.responseText);
```

to

```
$(this).parents('div').next().children('.results').html(data.responseText);
```

`$(this)` is a `li` so you need to find the parent `div` before finding the next child with the class `results`

Cut down version - but working example -> http://jsfiddle.net/bFHJc/

### Updated

Following discussions in chat it seems the markup in the question was incorrect .. here is the full markup :

```
<div class="table_settings"> 
   <div class="stats_options" style="width:130px;"> 
      <div style="float:left">Boekjaar: <span id="getYearPurchase">2012</span></div> 
      <div style="float:right; margin-top:11px;"></div> 
      <div class="clear"></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="option_list" style="width:150px; margin-top:0px;"> 
      <form id="formSales"> 
         <ul> 
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
         </ul> 
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="SALES" /> 
      </form> 
   </div> 
</div> 
<div class="table_content_results"> 
   <div class="results"></div>
</div>    ​
```

And this is the JavaScript 'locator' used to post to the `results` div:

```
$(this).parents('.table_settings').siblings('.table_content_results').children('.results').html();
```

Here is an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/9YWmW/3/

Comment: it wont - cause you just added the results div .. in a different place to where i assumed it was - 2 secs and i will update it

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen have you checked the value of `data.repsonseText` - can you change it to just add some text ie `.html('working')`

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen i have added a working example - using your HTML

Comment: I changed the value of the data and it doensn't work either. If I use this $(this).('.results').html(data.responseText); then everything works fine but it's not possible to duplicate

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your actual markup and I will have another look

Comment: I found the problem. The div with class option_list is inside another div. And the results is underneath the parents div of the option_list div. Is there a way to get the parent of a parent div? Grandparents div :-)

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen yes add another `.parent()` in after `.parents('div')`

Comment: I'm sorry but i just cannot get it working. I made a fiddle with my code, could you please take a look at it? Thanks in advance. http://jsfiddle.net/R45z5/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7850/discussion-between-manseuk-and-leon-van-der-veen)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(this).siblings('.results').html(data);
```

instead of

```
 $(this).siblings('.results').html(data.responseText);
```

in jquery you need not write responseText,It is needed in javascript ajax

or you can just write

```
$('div.results').html(data);
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work. The second will work but i use another option list with the same jQuery so i cannot use the class results

Comment: you want to populate data at same place , I mean in div with class option_list?